# Need help investigating memory leak in a complex TCL application

Tags: memory-leaks, tcl

I am investigating a possible memory leak with in a TCL application.
This application use a few in house developed DLL.
The application spawn multiple instances of the TCL interpreter.
(This is using TCL 8.4.13, I know this is old but so is this apps. lol)
It is running on Windows...

From reading on the web, I agree that leak most likely in one of the DLL.

I have thought(and start) looking at 3 ways to try to find that leak.
1. Using the "memory" command that can be included in TCL.
2. Using VC(Visual C) memory profiler.
3. Using VLD(Visual Leak Detector)

Each of them have it issues so far.  memory command give some issue because I need to rebuild the old interpreter AND all the included package that came with it.

VC gives me mainly "external code" as back trace...

VLD I was unable to make it work.  It left me with an empty report file.  I'm still investigating this one as I was only able to include it in our DLL build since I'm not building the old TCL interpreter and its packages.

I'm kind of new to TCL( a few months) so any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if any one know a little on how TCL manage its memory allocation would be nice.  I haven't found much on the web so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Tcl's got a fairly complex set of internal memory allocators layered on top of the basic system allocator. The goal of the layering is to reduce the frequency with which a global lock is required; Tcl's actually really quite good at this, even in highly-threaded applications. However, a consequence of this is that Tcl doesn't really release unused pages back to the operating system – it tends to assume that it is likely to need them again in the future, an assumption that is true in most application codes — and that can look like a memory leak. It isn't actually a leak, but can look like one. There are also a number of global caches that don't release memory, but they will stabilise the amount of memory they use at a fixed level.

But it is entirely possible for user code to leak memory. At the C level, this can be done most commonly by getting the reference counting on values wrong. At the Tcl level, the most common cause is storing lots of things in global variables (especially global arrays) and never unsetting them. These aren't bugs in Tcl *per se* but rather bugs in your code. Any programming language can have similar problems.

---

I would also note that Tcl 8.4.13 is wildly out of date. Even 8.4.20 is no longer supported, but that's at least got a chance of building on modern hardware. Tcl 8.5 is also in its long-term-support phase; there will probably only be one future release of it (unless we find a serious bug such as a security flaw). 8.6 is the current recommended-for-production release, and 8.7 and 9.0 are under development. While upgrading code from 8.4.* to 8.5 and later might be more work than you are willing to do, upgrading to 8.4.20 will definitely fix some bugs (I'd need to read the detail of the release notes to know which) and should be fairly straightforward. And if your problem is actually one of those fixed bugs, upgrading is the *only* solution we'll provide.

Comment: It's hard to say much more than that without a great deal more detail about what is going on, and there may be good reasons you can't tell me it.

Comment: The behavior I'm seeing is memory usage increase slowly over time but not linearly. It is increasing at startup then less over time. I would say like a logarithmic curve.  So, since it is an interpreter, my theory was that it could be normal.  Note that is doing it on a long run(weeks).  What I saw was like it kinda stabilized after months.  Since I didn't know much about how TCL works underneath I don't know if it make sense.